# Bounding the expected value of this random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $n, a \in \mathbb N$. Let $X$ be a random variable such that $$\mathbb P(X \leq \epsilon) \geq 1-a (1-\epsilon)^n.$$ I want to prove that $\mathbb E[X]$ is bounded by $\frac{\log(a)}{n}$ up to some constant factors.

This is my attempt

$$ \mathbb E[X] = \int^{\infty}_{0} \mathbb P(X > t)dt \leq \int^{\infty}_{0} a(1-t)^n dt.$$
Clearly the last integral diverges. I also thought of using $(1-t)^n \leq e^{-nt}$, but it also doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Your question makes no sense: since $a, n$ are positive integers, choose $a = n = 1$.  Then $\Pr[X \le \epsilon] \ge \epsilon$, and unless you restrict the support of $X$, this would imply for example $\Pr[X \le 2] \ge 2$.  But the limits of integration for the expectation is on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @heropup I suspect you need to restrict the support to $X\le 1$ since $\Pr[X \le 1] \ge 1$

Comment: @Henry If that is the case, then the bound is not valid; e.g., $a = 1$ is trivially wrong, and in general $$\operatorname{E}[X] \le 1 - \frac{n}{(n+1) \sqrt[n]{a}}$$ with equality holding when $$\Pr[X \le \epsilon] = \max(0, 1 - a(1-\epsilon)^n).$$

Comment: @heropup yes - I was just about to post exactly the same bound